# Xcode-project doesn't archive using NSKeyedArchiver, but Playground does

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, swift-playground

I'm having some problems archiving using NSCoding and NSObject. This works perfectly fine in Playground. But does not seem te work in Xcode. Can someone help me fix this problem?

Everytime I call:

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(person, toFile: "person")
```

It works and returns true in Playground, but it returns false in the project. I don't use simulator.

I've been looking for same type problems, however I can't seem to find anything related to this.

```
class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {

private var _name: String = "name"
private var _birthdate: Date = Date()
private var _income: Int = -1
private var _wealth: Int = -1

var name: String {
    get { return _name }
    set (newName) { _name = newName }
}
var birthdate: Date {
    get { return _birthdate }
    set (newBirthdate) { _birthdate = newBirthdate }
}
var income: Int {
    get { return _income }
    set (newIncome) { _income = newIncome }
}
var wealth: Int {
    get { return _wealth }
    set (newWealth) { _wealth = newWealth }
}

override init(){}

required convenience init(coder unarchiver: NSCoder) {

    self.init()

    if let name = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String {
        self.name = name
    }
    if let birthdate = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "birthdate") as? Date {
        self.birthdate = birthdate
    }
    let income = unarchiver.decodeInteger(forKey: "income")
    self.income = income

    let wealth = unarchiver.decodeInteger(forKey: "wealth")
    self.wealth = wealth

}

func encode(with archiver: NSCoder) {

    archiver.encode(name, forKey: "name")
    archiver.encode(birthdate, forKey: "birthdate")
    archiver.encode(income, forKey: "income")
    archiver.encode(wealth, forKey: "wealth")
} 
}
```

Then I create a person and archive it.

```
let person = Person()
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(person, toFile: "person")
```

Comment: It looks like an issue with the filePath. In my knowledge Playgrounds actually uses the Home directory but a project would use a sandbox. What happens if you use something like `FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("person")` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what FileManager does, but I've used it like this:

`let person = Person()
        
        let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("person")
        
        let personWasUploaded: Bool = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(person, toFile: "\(path)")
        
        print(path)
        print("person uploaded: \(personWasUploaded)")`

Comment: It creates a file like this:

`file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/4843FF38-BEFD-47F0-A1E2-DE4ADDAAD97F/Documents/person`. However, between Application and Documentts, the numbers/letters change each time

Comment: Is this something you can help me with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a small edit to your init in your Person class. Remove the `convenience` keyword and replace `self.init()` with `super.init()`:

```
class Person: NSObject, NSCoding {

    private var _name: String = "name"
    private var _birthdate: Date = Date()
    private var _income: Int = -1
    private var _wealth: Int = -1

    var name: String {
        get { return _name }
        set (newName) { _name = newName }
    }
    var birthdate: Date {
        get { return _birthdate }
        set (newBirthdate) { _birthdate = newBirthdate }
    }
    var income: Int {
        get { return _income }
        set (newIncome) { _income = newIncome }
    }
    var wealth: Int {
        get { return _wealth }
        set (newWealth) { _wealth = newWealth }
    }

    override init() {}

    required init(coder unarchiver: NSCoder) {

        super.init()

        if let name = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as? String {
            self.name = name
        }
        if let birthdate = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "birthdate") as? Date {
            self.birthdate = birthdate
        }
        let income = unarchiver.decodeInteger(forKey: "income")
        self.income = income

        let wealth = unarchiver.decodeInteger(forKey: "wealth")
        self.wealth = wealth

    }

    func encode(with archiver: NSCoder) {

        archiver.encode(name, forKey: "name")
        archiver.encode(birthdate, forKey: "birthdate")
        archiver.encode(income, forKey: "income")
        archiver.encode(wealth, forKey: "wealth")
    } 
}
```

Once you do that, you can call the archiver wherever you want (I did it in my  viewDidLoad just for testing and it worked) giving it a path like this:

```
let person = Person()
let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("person").path
let personWasUploaded: Bool = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(person, toFile:path)
print(path)
print("person uploaded: \(personWasUploaded)")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I found a way without the FileManager by just not using FileManager and also changing the init() like you suggested. I guess the main problem was with how I initialize.